# Django Rest Framework: Proper retrieve view doesn't handle request when I slightly change parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, request

I have this weird problem where when I try to retrieve one object from my database I receive the message `{"detail":"Not found."}`. I know the object is there because I can see it in my django admin. And when I try to retrieve another object it locates it fine.

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'recalls', views.Recalls)
admin.autodiscover()


from rest_framework import generics, permissions, serializers

from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/v1/recalls/rundate/<str:run_date>/', views.Recalls.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='retrieve_by_rundate'),
    path('o/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),,

]
```

views.py

```
class Recalls(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    This view will be fore retrieving a recall for a car from the database
    '''


    queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecallsSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]


    def list(self, request, **kwargs):

        queryset = GetRecalls.objects.all()
        serializer = RecallsSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        print('LIST')

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
        #record = get_list_or_404(queryset, self.kwargs)
        record = get_list_or_404(queryset, vin__exact=pk)
        serializer = RecallsSerializer(record, many=True)
        print('RETRIEVE')

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve_by_rundate(self, request, run_date=None):

        queryset = CarFax.objects.all()
        #record = get_list_or_404(queryset, self.kwargs)
        record = get_list_or_404(queryset, run_date__exact=run_date)
        serializer = RecallsSerializer(record, many=True)
        print('RETRIEVE RUNDATE')

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am using the URL `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/recalls/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$/'` (which is automatically created by `DefaultRouter()`. The issue is that when I look up with one parameter, let's say `test1`  so 
 `'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/recalls/test1'` it works, and in my console I can see the message "RETRIEVE" from my "retrieve" method being printed. However, when I replace that with another object I created and I know exists, it isn't located and that "RETRIEVE" message isn't printed. So that view obviously isn't even being reached, why is that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's "pk" of the second object ? Maybe regex dont valid this key. If it's for example "test+2", [\w-]+ will not valid this because available chars are ([0-9a-zA-Z_] and "-")

Comment: I thought of that too but I've tried just changing alphabetical characters too

Comment: As in I didn't add the "2" I just changed a letter

Comment: @CharlesSmith You seem to be doing a whole lot of manual work that the ModelViewSet already does. Also check your url `api/v1/recalls/rundate/<str:run_date>/` there seems to be a whole lot of unclear things here. You're omitting `rundate` in the path when making request. And what is it with the string argument? what do you expect there? `/api/v1/recalls/test1` definitely doesn't match that regex

Comment: thats for another endpoint, not the one I'm hitting in this example. The reason I'm doing the manual work is because I'm looking up by a field name and not the default 'pk'

Comment: Ok, now I see it, but why would you be trying to fetch a list in the retrieve object method?

Comment: and my bad the default URL is actually `/{pk}/$` so that's what it is hitting

Comment: Again, if you want to use another field instead of pk for detail lookup, you should just override the `lookup_field` in the view instead of all that manual work

Comment: I think I tried doing that before and it wasn't working, I'll try again though. I'm just not sure why this problem would arise? It works for my other endpoints. And I'm trying to return a list of objects that have a certain key. Not every object

Comment: And why do you have `retrieve` and `retrieve_by_rundate`? from your url configuration, `retrieve_by_rundate` is never used. Also, if you really want to manually specify how the object is retrieved, you should override the `get_object()` method and not retrieve. Here you're missing a call to the `get_object()` method so permissions will never be checked against the object

Comment: Using the retrieve object to return a list of objects instead of one is a bad design. You should consider a custom method for it instead. Or better of, use the field as a filter and return it through the normal list endpoint

Comment: I didn't include the `retrieve_by_rundate` method because it's not relevant to this post. Why is that bad design? And I'm using Django OAuth Toolkit right now so permissions isn't an issue. I'll look into the other method, but this is still a weird issue

Comment: I got rid of my retrieve function and used lookup_field instead. I get the same issue lol, I can find only one of the items that exist. But for every other one I can't

Comment: I'm an idiot, I was using the wrong model for my queryset, I was using CarFax instead of Recalls. Sorry boys